# Quick way to cross check controller variables with view variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Is there a quick (command OR gem OR test framework) to ensure that all View variables point to Controller variables?

I worked on a Rails app where a View variable was spelled incorrectly, and therefore did not display the data being called in the Controller. For example, `@person.name` is not displayed in the view.

```
Controller  
|- @person.name = 'first'  
|- @person.email = 'first@gmail.com'  
|- @person.cell = '123-456-7890'  

View  
|- display @person.nameE    # => NoMethodError
|- display @person.email    # => first@gmail.com
|- dispaly @person.cell     # => 123-456-7890
```

This will result in `@person.name` not displaying on the view since it is incorrectly pointed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `@person.nameE` won't return nil -- it'll raise `NoMethodError`. As long as you have a test loading that view, you'll see it blow up when you run it.

Comment: Pretty much anything will do! If you're looking for the gold standard in testing frameworks I'd start with Test::Unit. The [Ruby on Rails Testing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) has some great instruction on how to go about testing your Rails app.

Comment: I looked at the Testing Guide, and there was code to testing presence of specific HTML objects. This great if you know what you want to test for, but can this by extended to dynamically grow as the View's HTML objects change?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is just a pain that you will have to live with. This is a typical problem that happens when one is using a interpreted language. All you can do is write tests to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You write a view spec/test if you want to ensure that.

Answer (score 0):

There is, unfortunately, no way to ensure that variables or methods being accessed in the view are correctly set in the controller. The other posters are correct -- it will raise a NoMethodError and it's a best practice to write some tests for it.

Comment: but can the tests be dynamically updated? From what I saw in [Rails Testing Guide 4.6](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html), the tests were statically defined.